# "Control may reach end of non-void function" error message

Tags: c, compiler-errors, boolean

I want to write a bool custom function in C

```
//declare function
bool newjpg(BYTE buffer[]); 


//code of a function that check if it is a start of new jpeg, return true is conditions are met.
bool newjpg(BYTE buffer[])
    {
      if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
      return true;
    }
```

error message:

> control may reach end of non-void function

Comment: What happens if your if condition is false?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?  You don't handle the case where your condition is false.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `return` statement if the condition in the `if` isn't met. You could add it explicitly:

```c
bool newjpg(BYTE buffer[])
{
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or, more elegantly, just return the conditional expression:

```c
bool newjpg(BYTE buffer[])
{
    return (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a billion times!